# residuals() function error: replacement has x rows and data has y rows

Tags: r, replace

I have a data set that has reading time for each word that numerous individuals read.

I am trying to calculate reading time residuals for each individual in my data. Word lengths and the order of presentation (of a particular word) are factors in calculating a regression for each individual.

The reading time was log-transformed (logRT) and word lengths were calculated by nchar(). The order of presentation is also log-transformed.

```
model1<-lmer(logRT~wlen+log(order)+(1|subject), data=mydata)
```

Then, I try to get a residual column for every data point by doing the following,

```
mydata$logResid<-residuals(model1)
```

Then, I get this error.

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "LogResid", value = c(0.145113408056189,  : 
replacement has 30509 rows, data has 30800
```

Does anyone have any advice? I am totally confused. Since this is an analysis I've been doing every day with no such error so far. It is even more confusing.

Comment: Any `NA` in your data.frame?

Answer (score 2):

I would say you should try

```
model1 <- lmer(logRT~wlen+log(order)+(1|subject), data=mydata,
               na.action=na.exclude)
```

and see if that helps; it should fill in `NA` values in the appropriate places.

From `?na.exclude`:

> ... when ‘na.exclude’ is used the residuals and
>        predictions are padded to the correct length by inserting ‘NA’s
>        for cases omitted by ‘na.exclude’.